# React redux I'm having trouble sending data but I can pull it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to send data from the user form with react redux but I can't do it.

But when I manually type a name into initalstate, I can pull it into a different component.

I'm just learning. Here's my code.

**userSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState: {
        user: {
            name: null,
            surname: "",
            email: "",
            password: '',
            mAuth: true,
        },
    },
    reducers: {
        setNameLogin: (state, action) => {
            state.user.name = action.payload;
            return console.log(state.user.name, "state.user.name");
        },

    },
});

export const selectUserName = state => state.users.user.name;
export const mAuthCheck = state => state.users.user.mAuth;

export const { setNameLogin } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "../styles/login.css"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
//navigator imports
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
//redux imports
import { setNameLogin } from '../redux/users/usersSlice';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function LogIn() {
    const navigator = useNavigate();

    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState('');
    const [userMAuth, setUserMAuth] = useState(false);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onChangeName = (e) => {
        setUserName(e.target.value);
        // console.log(name, "name");
    }
    const onChangePassword = (e) => {
        setUserPassword(e.target.value);
        // console.log(password, "password");
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (userName.trim() === '' || userPassword.trim() === '') {
            alert("Please enter a name and password");
            return;
        }
        dispatch(setNameLogin({ userName, userPassword }));
        setUserName('');
        setUserPassword('');
        setUserMAuth(true);
        // console.log(name, password, "name, password");
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userMAuth, "mAuth");
    }, [userMAuth]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userName, "name");
    }, [userName]);


    const nextDashboardCheeck = () => {
        if (userName === "admin" && userPassword === "admin") {
            navigator("/Dashboard");
        }
        else
            alert("Please enter a valid name and password");
        return;
    }

    return (
        <div className='h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-4'>
            <div className='card-login  card'>
                <div className='title-head p-2'>
                    <h1 className='title-login text-center'>Login</h1>
                </div>
                <div className=' p-3'>
                    <div className='container'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-4 col-12'>
                                {/* <img className='img-thumbnail' style={{ width: '100%' }} src='https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/208-2088836_the-dashboard-reporting-of-delio-lead-management-have.png' alt='dashboard' /> */}
                            </div>
                            <Form className='col-md-8 col-12' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                                    <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter name" value={userName} onChange={onChangeName} />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>

                                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" value={userPassword} onChange={onChangePassword} />

                                </Form.Group>

                                <div className='p-1'>
                                    <Link to="/forgotPassword" style={{ color: "black" }} className='forgot-password p-2'>Forgot Password?</Link>
                                </div>
                                <div className='text-center'>
                                    <Button variant="primary" type="button" className='btn-login w-75'
                                        onClick={() => nextDashboardCheeck()}
                                    // onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                                    >
                                        Login
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                                <div className='text-center'>
                                    <p className='text-center p-2'>Don't have an account? <Link to="/">Signup </Link> </p>
                                </div>
                            </Form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div >
        </div >
    )
}

export default LogIn
```

```
store.js

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import usersSlice from "./users/usersSlice"

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        users: usersSlice,
    }
});
```

Here is all my code to send data.

Thank you.

I just identified it by name and it failed.

I have gone through all the threads like this on stack owerflow and I could not get it to work.

I tried to minimize my codes in userSlice and wrote each one to the console but the data was truncated.

**When I pull the data, I can pull the data when I write test to the user, to the name.**

Comment: You need attach the slice to store in order to use it i think. [link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

Comment: I already did this at startup I am importing the toolkit.